# Do I need LockService getScriptLock if my script has many users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, concurrency, atomic

My html form uploads data to a spreadsheet with a Google script. I use the following function to prevent a conflict, since many users are accessing the web app page:

```
function lockservice() {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);
  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

I have another script to retrieve the data (separate script), that also has many users accessing it. So do I need `getscriptlock` for that also?

In another words, is there a conflict between users occuring when getting the data or only when uploading it? or maybe in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing data to the spreadsheet with:

```
sheet.appendRow(array);
```

then you don't need Lock Service to write data.  If you are using:

```
sheet.getRange().setValues(array_2_D);
```

Then you do need Lock Service.

So, `appendRow()` is "atomic" and `setValues()` is not.  Atomic meaning that each operation runs completely independent from each other.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#appendRow(Object)

Getting values should use Lock Service if you have concurrent users.  There is also a quota limit for concurrent users.  The limit for "Simultaneous Executions" is 30, (at the time of this post)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations

Comment: Thanks pal for the corrections and the well explained answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have actually have the same understanding but:

I have a script where `Lock Service` is used and the locked section also includes a `appendRow()` operation to the sheet.
The script allows up to 30 concurrent executions.

Despite knowing that `appendRow()`is stated to be atomic, I now experience that **`appendRow()` actually may overwrite the last used row on a sheet!**

I never experienced this behavior without making use of the `Lock Service`.

Anybody else observed this unexpected behavior?

In the linked screenshot you see the new `Date()` value of the previous record being replaced instead of an entire new row being appended below.

Any thoughts & suggestions to overcome this behavior are highly appreciated.

Screenshot: appendRow() replaces last row of sheet:

[image: Screenshot: appendRow() replaces last row of sheet]